# Component polarity markings

Tags: soldering, components, solid-state-devices

Ok, I have my capacitor 4700 mikes should more than do the trick. I have my diode, soldering iron, jumpers and leads. Then I realized its been so long since I've installed solid state components I forgot how to do it. So  3 quick questions for clarification.

The painted end of the diode is the emitter so that end is connected to the cap and the other end to the source lead right?

The Arrows on the Cap point in the direction of current flow so I solder the emitter of the diode to the "base" of the arrow and the other to ground.?

Finally, I solder the diode/cap junction to the lead going to the voltage sensor right?

Comment: Huh? What are you trying to build?

Comment: You guys who put this on hold... except for Matt need to read the entire post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The painted end of the diode is the emitter

The end with a line around it is the *cathode*. If the cathode is connected to a more negative potential than the anode, the diode will conduct. It's orientation depends on it's purpose.

> The Arrows on the Cap point in the direction of current flow

Not all capacitors are polarised (care about +ve and -ve). Electrolytic capacitors typically are marked with a line next to the lead which should be most *negative*.

> I solder the diode/cap junction to the lead going to the voltage sensor right?

This depends entirely on what you are building. Reading the schematics for the circuit will answer this.

You may have had something like this in mind?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f9jG21.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: I knew I should have posted this as an answer to my own post but here's the application http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/97535/need-help-installing-a-capacitor

Comment: @Chris: See updated answer. It is best to include a link to the original question when writing a new follow-up question like this.

Comment: Yes, the logic looks right. Next question how do you do schematics in the exchange that is cool.

Comment: @Chris Ctrl+M in the text editor on this site.

Comment: Thanks for the Schematic. That is exactly what I was trying to describe and answered my questions. Most importantly it worked. Thanks again